# Correctly inserting a USB connector on the first try

Tags: technology

I don't want to force my USB port (which is rather easy to do, and may set fire to your computer<sup>[1]</sup>), so I'm rather careful when inserting a USB connector. The procedure often goes something like this:

1. Try to insert, doesn't seem to fit
2. Flip it over, try to insert, doesn't to fit again
3. *expletive*
4. GOTO 1 (50% chance)

How can I insert a USB connector ([type A](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsu/a/usb-type-a.htm)) correctly the first time? I don't want to force it.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>: Literally. [I have seen this happen](http://tmp.arp242.net/itmaybebroken.jpg).